# Как программно воспроизвести ноты?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

В проекте есть список нот:

```
List<Note> notesList
```

Как программно сделать так, чтобы по кнопке `Play` на экране был воспроизведен весь список нот по порядку?

Comment: Выводить звук произвольной частоты вы умеете?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мне просто дали задание такое, я ни разу со звуком не работал. Распарсил файл на байты, засэтал эти байты в модельку ноты, добавил все ноты в список. Как воспроизвести этот список я вообще без понятия.

Comment: Так и скажите "не умею". Что там вам дали, что вы сделали - абсолютно все равно, пока вы не умеете выдавать тупой синус в динамики. Ваша задача сводится к выводу (в простейшем случае) синусоидальной волны в динамик. Ищите решения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов какого-нибудь решения вы не знаете? или библиотеку может хорошую подскажите какую для моего решения? аудио - пока сложная тема для меня в освоении :(

Comment: Решение - искать, например по запросу Android play sine wave

Comment: Записать обратно в файл и воспроизвести плеером